# Reclaiming an abandoned city results in an error message

Tags: simcity-2013

Via the CityLog I found regions with abandoned cities. I click on a city which shows the details, what is has, what it looks like and its current name.
When I click the reclaim button, I get an error.

[image: You cannot claim this city because you don't own some of the content used to create it]

I have the deluxe version. What is the problem?

Comment: My best guess is a bug because the deluxe version includes all "bonus" content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The city you are trying to reclaim contains buildings that you do not have access to. This is likely because they were made with a DLC pack that your account does not have loaded. Unfortunately the error message is not accurate enough to give you specifics... unless that information is some where else on the error screen.

With the updated part of the question (you have the deluxe edition with the currently available DLC) I would have to say you are experiencing a bug with the games acknowledgement of that DLC. One of the people I play with has the same issue actually, he shows as using the Limited Edition when he logs in (so what Origin thinks he has) despite having the deluxe edition. He has access to the items in the cities he starts but has not tried to claim a city. If this is indeed the case for you as well then I am not sure of what else you can do but contact EA/Origin Support to try and work it out.

Comment: I have the deluxe version. Is there other DLC?

Comment: If you own deluxe, there is no additional DLC you could get. So your answer should be considered wrong.

Comment: @user28015 Ah, that was not part of the original question.

Comment: I had tagged the question with simcity-deluxe but someone edited it out! sorry for that, you answered before i discovered that edit. I then realized simcity-deluxe referred to to SimCity 3000

Comment: @Valamas Well I hope my updated info is more helpful but I realize 'Talk to EA' is not the answer you were hoping for.