# How do I play with others in neighbourhoods ... cannot access

Tags: simcity-2013

Ok, I don't get it. 
I don't have any origin friends and cannot find any neighbourhood with vacant cities. When I finally find a lot, it says I cannot access it because I don't have items used in the city. What what what? Makes no sense to me, and let's face it, it's no fun playing SimCity solo. How do I become part of a neighbourhood?

Answer (score 1):

i feel you are asking two questions. One, why do i get the message that I do not have the content:
[Reclaiming an abandoned city results in an error message](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108641/reclaiming-an-abandoned-city-results-in-an-error-message)

Second: how to join a game with other people:
[Joining a game with an empty slot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108028/joining-a-game-with-an-empty-slot/108636#108636)

This question should be closed if I have answered your questions.